# Manage Checked Listview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listview, checked

I have a listview configured to use checkboxes.
Now I need the listview.text value of each checked value in a String variable comma-seprated.
Of course, unchecking one value should remove this from the variable.
I am desperately failing here.
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm feeling generous so even though you have an extreme lack of detail, here you go:

```
Private Sub YourListView_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles YourListView.ItemChecked
    Dim yourString = String.Join(",", YourListView.CheckedItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Select(Function(li) li.Text))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a genius. And a generous one on top.